# Deferred jQuery AJAX request does not run done() callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred, mockjax

I have setup a simple demo using jQuery Deferred object with AJAX request to simulate how my app is doing it.

My issue is, ever since I switched over from the older non-deferred method, I cannot get a success callback.

Only the `fail()` callback is called.  Can someone help me to get a successful callback?  I don't see where it is going wrong?  Appreciate any help

My demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/y645yp4g/4/

**My old AJAX call was like this...**

```
var ajax = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/gettask',
    data: {
        action: 'load-task-record',
        task_id: taskId
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // my success functionality here
    }
});
```

**New AJAX call using Deferred object...**

```
// Call function that execute AJAX request and returns it
var ajaxRequest = ajaxLoadTaskData();

ajaxRequest.done(function(response) {

    if( response.success ) {
        alert('AJAX request success');
    }else{
        // output the contents of response.errors
    }

}).fail(function(response) {
    // AJAX request failed
    console.log('response', response);
    alert('AJAX request failed');

}).always(function(response) {

});


// Run AJAX request and return Promise()
function ajaxLoadTaskData() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/gettask',
        data: {
            action: 'load-task-record',
            task_id: '1',
        },
    });
}
```

**Mock AJAX response for AJAX request to /gettask**

```
// Mock AJAX response for AJAX request to /gettask
$.mockjax({
    url: '/gettask',
    contentType: 'text/json',
    responseTime: 100,
    response: function(settings) {
        console.log('mockJax GET to /gettask :');
        //console.log(settings);
        if (settings.data.value == 'err') {
            this.status = 500;
            this.responseText = 'Validation error!';
        } else {
            var taskrecord = { 'name1': 'bar' };
            this.responseText = taskrecord;
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: *"As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success()."*

Comment: Additionally, `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` doesn't match the data you are sending: `data: {
        action: 'load-task-record',
        task_id: taskId
    }`. If you wanted to send JSON to the server, you should send json, not an object that will be converted to form params.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks!  I was using `async: false ` to get around the issue I was having before by not using Deferred.  So I finally decided to switch it over but forgot to change that part. thanks a bunch

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/y645yp4g/9/ I have update jQuery and changed `async: true`.  ANy other ideas why it would still `fail()`?

Comment: failing due to 404 atm. Guessing the mockjax isn't working.

Comment: @KevinB Yeah I keep seeing that but right after it it shows `XHR finished loading: POST "http://fiddle.jshell.net/gettask".` perhaps my MockJax library is having troubble with this

Comment: That was it, chaged my post URL to JSFiddles AJAX one `/echo/json/` and success, thanks for the help

Comment: @JasonDavis, hey, i'm seeing that you are on a way of structuring an API using jQuery.ajax as base. Take a look at this plugin (i'm the author) and see if you will find it useful for that: https://github.com/DiegoZoracKy/AjaxAPIFactory

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy Hey thanks for sharing, that does look like an interesting library, clean!

Comment: First thing I'd do is get rid of those hanging commas!

Comment: @JasonDavis Good to know that you liked.

Answer (score 0):

***/gettask*** doesn't exists in that jsFiddle environment. Use console.log(settings) to see the entire content of the response. You will se that the ***status*** is 404.